# Deploying ReactJS app Production

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have finished my ReactJS app and I want to put it in production. I run next command: `webpack --progress -p` but in chrome F12 I get next error: `index.js:1 Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. See WebSiteFbReactJs for more details.`.

It is my webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const WEBPACK = require('webpack');
const PATH = require('path');
const CopyFiles = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BaseName = "/upct";

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        /*path: './public',*/
        publicPath: BaseName+'/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: PATH.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    "presets": [
                        "es2015",
                        "react",
                        "stage-0"
                    ],
                    "plugins": [
                        "react-html-attrs",
                        "transform-decorators-legacy",
                        "transform-class-properties"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new WEBPACK.DefinePlugin({
            BASENAME: JSON.stringify(BaseName)
        })
    ]
}
```

What could this error be?. It is all OK, right? How could I solve this? Thank you.

EDIT: I am getting next error too: `DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://MYSERVER.com/upct/src/css/bootstrap.css.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `NODE_ENV = 'production'` environmental variable to your Webpack build in order to disable debug information and warnings, most of the property type checks and other developer-friendly tools. It will make the app faster but harder to debug. Use this only when deploying to the production.

In your case, in the `plugins` section just add:

```
new WEBPACK.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
}),
```

Please see [documentation about optimizing the production build with React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build), especially [Webpack section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#webpack).

As for the error with the source maps, it seems that the link is broken and returns 404 Not Found error so Chrome can't fetch the original source code mapping for Bootstrap's CSS. That's not a big issue as you probably won't be looking at it's source but that might be a signal that your Webpack build doesn't deploy source maps when building the app. Please add [`devtool: 'source-map'`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) to your config file in order to produce source maps which will improve the debugging experience on production by translating bundled code to original source files.

[UglifyJs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) will minimize the code size by renaming variables, function names and by other optimization tricks. You can add it to your `plugins` section of the config file the same way:

```
new WEBPACK.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
        // suppresses warnings, usually from module minification
        warnings: false,
    },
}),
```

There are many possible optimizations, for more information please see this [optimization guide](http://moduscreate.com/optimizing-react-es6-webpack-production-build/).

Comment: Ok! Thank you! Then, if I am not on production (for next projects) I only delete `'production'` and put `'developing'` for example?. I tryed it and it is working! Thank you!. I do not need any more to make project more efficient right? As `optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` as I see on documentation... I am not sure. Also, I have add an Edit: on my ask, please, see it, thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I have updated the answer about the source maps and UglifyJs. For the dev/production settings, you can change the values or comment/uncomment them or create two separate config files - one for production and one for development. You may also use `ifs` and set different values if you like.